# How to deal with an unknown number of nextTokens

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to write a lambda function that'll take in every new logstream created in CloudWatch Logs and then paste them into a new log group.

So far, I've been using a try catch block to take care of nextTokens that come up. The Try block will be the initial put_log_event call and then when I'm thrown an error, I take the expectedSequenceToken and then use that in the except block.

```
       try:
            for event in log_dict['logEvents']:        
                response = cloudwatch.put_log_events(
                    logGroupName = log_group_name,
                    logStreamName = stream_name,
                    logEvents = [
                        {
                            'timestamp': event['timestamp'],
                            'message' : event['message']
                        }
                    ]
                )
                # next_token = response['nextSequenceToken']
                # while len(next_token) > 0:
                #     response = cloudwatch.put_log_events(
                #         logGroupName = log_group_name,
                #         logStreamName = stream_name,
                #         logEvents = [
                #             {
                #                 'timestamp': event['timestamp'],
                #                 'message' : event['message']
                #             }
                #         ],
                #         sequenceToken = next_token
                #     )

                #     next_token = response['nextSequenceToken']

        except botocore.client.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidSequenceTokenException':
                response = cloudwatch.put_log_events(
                    logGroupName = log_group_name,
                    logStreamName = stream_name,
                    logEvents = [
                        {
                            'timestamp': event['timestamp'],
                            'message' : event['message']
                        }
                    ],
                    sequenceToken = e.response['expectedSequenceToken']
                )
```

The problem is that when the except block throws the same error with a another expectedSequenceToken, I don't know how to handle that.

I've tried implementing a do while loop like in the code snippet above but I run into an issue of the same log message being pasted multiple times.

Also, any clarification of what the purpose the sequenceToken serves would be super helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop would push the same event over and over.  I would add code to get the nextSequence before you start the events loop and it should work.

```
        response = cloudwatch.describe_log_streams(logGroupName = log_group_name, logStreamNamePrefix = stream_name)
        next_token = response['logStreams'][0]['uploadSequenceToken']

        for event in log_dict['logEvents']:        
            response = cloudwatch.put_log_events(
                sequenceToken = next_token 
                logGroupName = log_group_name,
                logStreamName = stream_name,
                logEvents = [
                    {
                        'timestamp': event['timestamp'],
                        'message' : event['message']
                    }
                ]
            )
            next_token = response['nextSequenceToken']
```